# Спарсить значение

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Нужно к себе спарсить информацию о тендерах http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/quicksearch/search.html

Пробую реализовать `через simple_html_dom`. Их новости получилось спарсить, информацию о тендерах — нет.

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php'; // библиотека для парсинга
           // $username = 'durov'; // Имя в twitter
            $maxpost = '5'; // к-во постов
            $html = file_get_html('http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/quicksearch/search.html');
            $i = '0';
            foreach ($html->find('div.registerBox') as $article) { //выбираем все li сообщений
                $item['text'] = $article->find('div.reportBox', 0)->innertext; // парсим текст сообщения в html формате
                $item['time'] = $article->find('ul', 0)->innertext; // парсим время в html формате
                $articles[] = $item; // пишем в массив
                $i++;
                if ($i == $maxpost) break; // прерывание цикла
            }

                for ($j = 0; $j < $maxpost; $j++) {
                    echo '<div class="twitter_message">';
                    echo '<p class="twitter_text">' . $articles[$j]['text'] . '</p>';
                    echo '<p class="twitter_time">' . $articles[$j]['time'] . '</p>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
```

Ошибки:

`Warning: file_get_contents(http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/quicksearch/search.html) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\simple_html_dom.php on line 31`

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\pars.php on line 9

Подскажите, как быть.

Comment: `simple_html_dom.php` точно находится в той же папке что и файл `pars.php` ?

Comment: Да точно,с новостями то работает.

Comment: А у вас включено отображение `warning` сообщений? Возможно парсер не может просто загрузить страницу и выдает что-то типа ` failed to open stream: HTTP request failed` а вы этого не наблюдаете.. в результате и остальное обламывается

Comment: А что Вы имеете ввиду под отображением,мне выдает то,что выше видно.Warning и  Fatal error

Comment: У вас же в первом warning явно сказано `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` он не получил страницу по указанному URL

Comment: @zkolya У них на закупках видимо какая то защита стоит. может куки какие, может еще что. Ваш URL отлично открывается в браузере, но если его попробовать скачать например wget - он дает 404

Comment: http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/main/public/news/news.html хорошо открывает

Comment: А что Вы можете посоветовать делать? Или тут уже никак?

Comment: @zkolya Ну это долгая иcследовательская работа. Сначала curl пробовать эмулировать все заголовки обычного браузера, если не помогает начинаем  рассматривать js которые у них на странице срабатывают. Я бы не мучился и делал на JS плагин к хрому, который спарсит нужные данные со страницы и перешлет их в удобном виде php скрипту который уже в базу положит или что там ему положено делать. Да и по DOM на JS удобнее ходить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте `curl` с разными параметрами.
Для вашего примера должно работать вот так:

```
include './domParser/simple_html_dom.php';
$maxpost = '5'; // к-во постов            
$url = 'http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/quicksearch/search.html';

$ch = curl_init($url);          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.125 Safari/533.4");
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();          
$html->load($curl_scraped_page, true, false);

$i = '0';

foreach ($html->find('div.registerBox') as $article) { //выбираем все li сообщений
    $item['text'] = $article->find('div.reportBox', 0)->innertext; // парсим текст сообщения в html формате
    $item['time'] = $article->find('ul', 0)->innertext; // парсим время в html формате
    $articles[] = $item; // пишем в массив
    $i++;
    if ($i == $maxpost) break; // прерывание цикла
}

for ($j = 0; $j < $maxpost; $j++) {
    echo '<div class="twitter_message">';
    echo '<p class="twitter_text">' . $articles[$j]['text'] . '</p>';
    echo '<p class="twitter_time">' . $articles[$j]['time'] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

пример: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/innq-pc89

Comment: Большое спасибо за столь подробное разъяснение!Не подскажите как быть со следующими страницами,а то выводит максимум 10 записей

Comment: @zkolya вообще, по-хорошему, надо сделать отдельно две функции. Первая парсит страницу, вторая анализ надо ли переходить на другую страницу (то есть анализирует DOM у пагинатора, если тот существует). И из первой вызывать вторую.  А во второй, если анализ показал, что можно перейти на следующую-берет ссылку и вызывает первую функцию. По сути получится рекурсия между ними пока не достигет последней страницы. Вот вам пример для разбора http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6ept-k70m